# Alternative to tf.compat.v1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to migrate my tf1 codes into tf2.

For this purpose, I changed the following functions as follows:

`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy()`into`tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy()`
`tf.train.MomentumOptimizer()`into`tf.compat.v1.train.MomentumOptimizer()`
`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()`
into  `tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step()`

However, I want to rewrite my codes in tf2 directly without using `tf.compat.v1`

How is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting from TF1 to TF2  code, you can do it easily by using the tf.keras api in TF2. For example the functions your provided.

`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy()` to
`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`
`from_logits` parameter here specifies whether y_pred is expected to be a logits tensor.

`tf.train.MomentumOptimizer()` to `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(momentum=...)`
by providing the `momentum` parameter.

As for the final function its still being used in the TF2.0 documentation so maybe there isn't an equivalent version in 2.0.

You can check the this guide from the TF2.0 website whic would provide a great refrence for you. [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)